Video game where you are a part of a group of astronauts stuck on some other planet and you need to build a house and discover stuff
The title pretty much says it all. I once saw the game being played on an indie game YouTube channel, which I'm pretty sure was Pravus.
It was 3D and singleplayer. You view the game from a third-person view, but you're the guy who makes all of the decisions and such.

More details would make the question better. 3D or 2D? What did the game look like? Single player? Presumably Indie developer, but any idea of the platform? Or age of the game? As it stands, I could (very weakly) argue the both Pikmin (spaceship? House? Same function) and Minecraft (build houses, discover stuff) could fit the bill, but I doubt it’s either.

As demonstrated, you have details of a game genre, not a game title (I would guess rimworld)

I voted to close as too broad until further details are provided, since there are already 5 answers that all match in a way or another, plus there still might be more (off my mind, Rimworld and Ixion also fit that description).

I guessed statistically I could probably find the answer since Pravus is a single ,if prolific, video maker and there has to be a limit to how many videos he has made invovling games with people stuck on a planet gathering resources and building houses. So I  posted my 5 best guesses and it was one of them.

Or maybe Stranded Alien Dawn. Made by the same people who made Surviving Mars but quite a different game.
Here the stranded people are building a house.





This is the one.

Happy I could find it for you.

Possibly Planetbase. Though the people don't seem to have been stranded there.





Offworld Trading Company: Jupiter's Forge
Again not stuck here, seems like they planned to be here




Surviving Mars possibly.
There are many versions of Surviving Mars that Pravus has played through.m
Here is a screenshot of gameplay from this one.





Not the one, but this is a fun one as well.

Synergy



This one does not seem to be fully released yet but fits your description.
